# Find exponential-function given multiple points

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I've created a program in Python 3 which estimates an exponential function in the form `y = a * b^x` given multiple measurement points.

I'm not the first to do this as there are many programs out there that does the exact same thing, but I'm interested in how they do it if they do it better than me (which they probably do).

Here's the code if you want to read it (not necessary):

```
from math import log, exp

# The function will first be estimated in the form y = a*e^(kx)
# and then converted to the form y = a*b^x where b = e^x

xList = []    # Contains all the x-values
yList = []    # Contains all the corresponding y-values
kList = []    # Contains all the k-values
aList = []    # Contains all the a-values

n = int(input("How many points will you input?: "))

for i in range(n):
    x, y = map(float, input("Please enter an x-value and its corresponding y-value:\n").split())
    xList.append(x)
    yList.append(y)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        # The k-value is calculated as k = ln(y1/y2)/(x1-x2)
        kList.append(log(yList[i]/yList[j]) / (xList[i]-xList[j]))

# Because the points given are supposed to be from physical experiments
# the k-value will not be constant throughout all measurements.
# To go around this I take the average of all k-values
k = sum(kList)/len(kList)

for i in range(n):
    # The a-value is calculated as a = y1/e^(kx1)
    aList.append(yList[i]/exp(k*xList[i]))

# Taking the average for the same reason as the k-value
a = sum(aList)/len(aList)

# Calculating the b-value
b = exp(k)

fin = "y = " + str(a) + " * " + str(b) + "^x"

print("\n")
print("The estimated function is:\n{}".format(fin))
```

Sorry for my horrendous code

To those that don't want to read my code, here's how I do it:

1. We want to find a function `y = a * b^x`
2. We will first estimate the function in the form `y = a * e^(k*x)`
3. Given the x-values `{x1, x2, x3, ..., xn}` and their corresponding y-values `{y1, y2, y3, ..., yn}` we estimate the k-value
4. The k-value for points `(xi, yi)` and `(xj, yj)` is calculated as `k = ln(y1/y2) / (x1-x2)`
5. Calculate all k-values for points (xi, yi) (xj, yj) such that i < j and set the final k-value as the average
6. Given the k-value we can now calculate the a-value for a point `(xi, yi)` as `a = yi / e^(k*xi)`
7. Calculate the a-value for all points and take the average
8. Finally calculate the b-value as `b = e^k`

What can I do to get a better and faster estimation?

Comment: To average the coefficients for pairs of points is a good idea. But you might want to look up [Least Square fit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) algorithms. Additional suggestions: Write a polynomial fit function. Then you can reuse the linear fit from your polynomial fit for exponential (lny, x) and logarithmic (y, lnx) fits. Three in one. And a good regression analysis calculates a correlation coefficient r² to let you know, how well the function represents your data points.